# How often should I do fuel induction and why should I do it if my car runs perfectly fine?

Tags: corolla

I've owned 6 cars now and I only remembered doing fuel induction once.  Yesterday I went to the Toyota dealer and they recommended me doing fuel induction every 3000 miles.  I have a 2009 Toyota Corolla.  How often should I do fuel induction and why should I do it if my car runs perfectly fine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm hoping you may have missed a zero in the recommended service interval in your question. Modern cars don't even recommend oil changes more frequently than 5,000 miles, so an induction service every 3,000 miles is just crazy.

Some dealers recommend induction service every 30,000 miles, but even then, I feel this is just a money-maker for them, and I doubt your owners manual would include any induction service in the maintenance schedule.

I feel if the car does not have any running or idle problems, then save your money. Quality gasoline has detergent additives anyway.

I'm not alone in this feeling, Tom and Ray of CarTalk have a [similar opinion](http://www.dallasnews.com/business/columnists/car-talk/20120210-is-induction-service-a-waste-of-money.ece).

Comment: I thought so too but just wasn't sure, thanks so much for the detailed answer!

Answer (score 3):

I'm looking at the 2009 Corolla: Scheduled Maintenance Guide that you can find on [the nicely organized Toyota site](http://www.toyota.com/owners/web/pages/resources/owners-manuals?p_p_id=changemodelyear_WAR_toyotaownersonlineportlet&p_p_lifecycle=1&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&_changemodelyear_WAR_toyotaownersonlineportlet_action=processRequest&_changemodelyear_WAR_toyotaownersonlineportlet_javax.portlet.action=processRequest#Warranty-Maintenance-Guides).  The closest thing to a fuel induction service is an inspection of "Fuel lines and connections, fuel tank band and fuel tank vapor vent system hoses" every 30K miles:

> Visually inspect for corrosion, damage, cracks, and loose or leaking
>   connections. Tighten connections or replace parts as necessary.

In theory, the "induction service" might be the "replace parts."  However, it also says "as necessary."  If there isn't a problem, I don't think this is worth your money.

*That said, it's always fun to ask someone to explain in detail all the magic beans and lucky rabbits feet that they're going to rub on your car to make it more better.*